# MongoDB - Updating multiple levels of subdocuments with multiple $elemMatch operators in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm very new to MongoDB, so please have mercy on me! I have a schema that looks like this:

```
{
    "hour": 0,
    "minutes": [
        {
            "minute": 0,
            "minuteVolume": 0,
            "seconds": [
                {
                    "second": 0,
                    "secondVolume": 0
                },
                {
                    "second": 1,
                    "secondVolume": 0
                }
        },
        {
            "minute": 22,
            "minuteVolume": 0,
            "seconds": [
                {
                    "second": 0,
                    "secondVolume": 0
                },
                {
                    "second": 1,
                    "secondVolume": 0
                }
        }],
    "hourVolume": 0
}
```

I'm trying to update a specific `"secondVolume"` and `"minuteVolume"`. I've tried the following:

```
collection.update({"hour": hour, 
    "minutes": {$elemMatch: {"minute": minute}},
    "minutes.seconds": {$elemMatch: {"second": second}}},
            { $inc: {hourVolume: 1, "minutes.$.minuteVolume": 1, "minutes.$.minuteVolume.seconds.$.second": 1}
                },
        {upsert:false,safe:true},
        function(err,data){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
                {
                console.log(data);
                }
        }
    );
```

- but I'm clearly doing something wrong. If I remove the `$elemMatch` for `"second"` and only try to update the `"minuteVolume"`, it works just groovy. This leads me to believe that I'm doing something wrong with the positional operators or that my query isn't unwinding the document properly.

Is this even possible with a single query in MongoDB? I'm using mongodb driver version 1.4.19.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can me and the 240 people who have voted for this feature. 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

If you know the position of the elements (possibly by querying the document first) you can update by using positional operators instead of by using $elemMatch.

```
{ $inc: {hourVolume: 1, "minutes.0.minuteVolume": 1, "minutes.0.minuteVolume.seconds.2.second": 1 }
```

I've had to redo several schemas to prevent multi-nesting and therefore allow for a one-shot update.

Comment: Hi Will. This is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up building an $inc object using positional operators, as I did indeed know the position of elements. You saved me! Thanks, Kevin